# Normal sheaf of a nonsingular subvariety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I would like a reference to a proof or a proof of the following fact.

Let $ X $ be a nonsingular variety over an algebraically closed field $ k $ and $ Y $ a nonsingular subvariety of $ X $ of codimension $ 1 $ and with ideal sheaf $ \mathcal{I} = \mathcal{O}_X(-Y) $. Note that the sheaf $ \mathcal{I} / \mathcal{I}^2 $ on $ X $ is supported on $ Y $ which we call by the same. Then we have $ \mathcal{I} / \mathcal{I}^2 = \mathcal{I}|_Y = \mathcal{O}_Y(-Y) $, or in other words, the normal sheaf is given by $ \mathcal{O}_Y(Y) $.

Comment: If the codimension of $Y$ is greater than 1, its ideal is not invertible, so it is not a good idea to use the notation $\mathcal{O}_X(-Y)$ for it.

Comment: I missed the codimension one part, thanks.

Comment: The isomorphism $I/I^2 \cong I\vert_Y$ is explained in Hartshorne and it holds independently on the codimension.

Comment: Can you please cite the page number? The only place I've seen this is in proposition 8.20 (chapter 2) where Hartshorne just says it for the codimension one case without proof.

Comment: I don't remember the page number, but the argument is quite straightforward: just taking the exact sequence $0 \to I \to \mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0$ and tensoring it by $I$, one obtains $I \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} I \to I \to I \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_Y \to 0$. Now it remains to note that the first map is induced by the multiplication, so its image is $I^2$, and $ I \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{O}_Y = I\vert_Y$.